# analogRead(0) or analogRead(A0)

Tags: arduino, software, pins, analog, digital-logic

The arduino reference [states](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/analogRead) that you would use the following code to read the value from analog pin #5:

```
int val1 = analogRead(5);
```

However to read from digital pin #5, you would pass the same pin number to `digitalRead`:

```
int val2 = digitalRead(5);
```

Shouldn't you use `analogRead(A5)` instead of `analogRead(5)`?

If not, what does the following code do:

```
int val3 = analogRead(A5);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**To answer Tyilo's specific questions:**

`analogRead(5)` and `digitalRead(5)` will read from two different places. The former will read from analog channel `5` or `A5` and the latter will read from pin 5 which *happens* to be a digital pin. So yes, if you want to read an analog pin with `digitalRead` you should be using `A5`.

**Why?**

`analogRead` requires a channel number internally but it will allow you to give it a pin number too. If you do give it a pin number it will convert it to its corresponding channel number. As far as I can tell `analogRead` is the only function which uses a channel number internally, is the only one to allow a channel number, and is the only function with this undocumented pin-to-channel conversion. To understand this let's start off with some examples.

If you want to use `analogRead` on the first analog pin `A0` you can do `analogRead(0)` which uses the channel number or `analogRead(A0)` which uses the pin number. If you were to use the pin number variant, `analogRead` would convert the pin number `A0` to its proper channel number `0`.

If you want to use `digitalWrite` on the first analog pin `A0` you can *only* do `digitalWrite(A0, x)`. `digitalWrite` doesn't use analog channels internally and does not let you pass it a channel number. Well, it'll *let* you but you'll select the wrong pin. The same applies to `digitalRead` and even `analogWrite`.

What about the pin-to-channel conversions done by `analogRead`? The source for that function can be found in `hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c` You'll see that it does some simple subtraction based on the board type. The `A0`/`A1`/`A2`/etc. constants represent the pin number of the analog channels and can be used everywhere you need to refer to the analog inputs. For that reason they are the best option to use in your Arduino code because it's very obvious that you're using the same physical port even when you're using different functions. The definitions of those constants depend on your board.

For example, here's the analog pin definition code for the Arduino Uno in `hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h`

```
static const uint8_t A0 = 14;
static const uint8_t A1 = 15;
static const uint8_t A2 = 16;
static const uint8_t A3 = 17;
static const uint8_t A4 = 18;
static const uint8_t A5 = 19;
static const uint8_t A6 = 20;
static const uint8_t A7 = 21;
```

For comparaison here is the analog pin definition code for the Arduino Mega:

```
static const uint8_t A0 = 54;
static const uint8_t A1 = 55;
static const uint8_t A2 = 56;
[...]
static const uint8_t A13 = 67;
static const uint8_t A14 = 68;
static const uint8_t A15 = 69;
```

Further EE discussion on analog pins: [Can I use the analog pins on the Arduino for my project as digital?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/67103/3353)

Comment: I though it was exactly like you explained, I just got confused by the Arduino reference, which contains false information.

Comment: Also you can **only** do `analogRead` on analog pins! On the other hand, `analogWrite` can be used on both the analog and the PWM pins.

Comment: @Tyilo I updated my response with some more accurate information taken from the source code.

Comment: analogWrite() can be called on any of the pins, but it only does something on the PWM pins.  On non-PWM ditial pins and all analog pins, it simply calls digitalWrite().

Comment: @JamesC4S Yet another undocumented "feature" :\

Comment: Hi @Tyilo, I'm also very disappointed of the Arduino reference in many ways! I was always wondering if it's only me...

Comment: @powtac - It's generally accepted that the arduino documentation is fairly abominable, at least around here. Don't feel like you're missing something, it's not you, it's the arduino people.

Answer (score 3):

I spent hours on this. I thought I had a hardware problem. It turns out that I was calling `analogRead()` incorrectly.

Incorrect (erroneous sample code from [DFRobot](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Capacitive_Soil_Moisture_Sensor_SKU_SEN0193) ):

```
val = analogRead(0); //connect sensor to Analog 0
```

Correct:

```
val = analogRead(A0); //connect sensor to Analog 0
```

**Update**: `analogRead()` takes GPIO pin numbers. `A0` etc. are #defines for Arduino pin numbers, where `A0 == 36`.

Be careful: on e.g. the FireBeetle ESP32, pin labeled "IO36/A0" (GPIO36) equals Arduino `A0`, but "IO39/A1" (GPIO39) equals Arduino `A3` (not `A1`), "IO34/A2" (GPIO34) equals Arduino `A6` (not `A2`), etc.